# Unable to run code on device

Tags: android

When I try to run code on device I am getting the below mentioned error.

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I tried reseting adb. Still did not work. Please help.

Comment: What does `adb devices` command give you? Have you enabled usb debugging?

Comment: Close all app on your device please.Kill service in your device as possible.Because the process you can use  is less than 64 if you want to use adb.Then use adb devices to see if your devices is listed.If not ,cancel debug auth in mobile and then turn off and turn on debug switch.

Comment: The device is detected. When I click run studio tries to lauch the app but then fails with the above error